# Do I need to collect my luggage on a layover in Singapore?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, layovers, qatar-airways, sin

I am flying from Bali to Mashhad. I bought the ticket from Qatar airways. My flight is:

1. Bali → Singapore (operated by Indonesia Airways)
2. Singapore → Doha (Qatar Airways)
3. Doha → Mashhad (Qatar Airways)

Do I need to collect my bag in Singapore as they are under different airlines, though I booked it together?

Comment: can you provide flight numbers please